# How to remove files inside the hadoop directory if there exists any?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using below command to do that. Please note this is working fine if there are any contents in that folder

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /home/user/folder/*
```

But am getting an error when the folder is EMPTY ": No such file or directory".

My requirement is it should delete any contents if there exists. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

First run command with `-test -d` then `&&` to short-circuit the `rm` command if it doesn't exist.

```
hadoop fs -test -d /home/user/folder && hadoop fs -rm -r /home/user/folder/*
```

Alternatively, ignore the error because the path is already deleted.